# Безопасная организация хранения разметки и стилей в JavaFX-приложениях

Tags: java, javafx

### Описание проблемы

Для того, чтобы убедиться, что FXML-макет в Scene Builder-e построен корректно, необходимо добавить в него контент, который в готовом приложении будет динамическим. Например, если это Grid View из товаров, которые в приложении будут генерироваться на основе данных, то необходимо отрисовать несколько товаров вручную; если это Card View адресной книги - то отрисовать несколько карточек адресатов.

Далее, когда отрисовка макета будет завершена, нужно вынуть из него весь контент, который будет генерироваться динамически. А если мы захотим модифицировать стилизацию? А если нужно будет что-то подправить? А если мы захотим добавить другую тему? Опять придётся отрисовывать динамический контент, а после окончания отрисовки - всё удалять. Нетехнологично. Решением является разделения каждой сцены на два FXML-файла: версии с мок-данными и окончательной версии только со статическим контентом.

### Вопрос

Если готовые к обработке Java-ой макеты хранятся обычно `src\main\resources\views`, то где можно *безопасно* хранить исходные макеты с мок-данными в maven-проекте?

Уверен, многие отвечающие скажут: за пределами проекта, то есть вне `src`. Если бы речь шла только об FXML-файлах, то особых причин возражать у меня бы не было. Но вместе с FXML-файлами с мок-данными удобно хранить исходные файлы CSS-препроцессоров (тогда, можно писать стили на каком-нибудь CSS-препроцессоре, а он будет складывать выходные файлы в `src\main\resources`). Тут уже гораздо больше требуется, чтобы FXML с мок данными и файлы препроцессоров были как мимум в одной папке, родительской по отношению к `src`. Какие безопасные варианты Вы ещё можете порекомендовать?

Comment: По GridView, если я правильно понял, вы получаете список элементов, на их основе высчитываете, сколько потребуется ячеек, и создаете GridView нужного размера, потом по индексу обращаетесь к ячейке и заполняете ее разными элементами?

Comment: @Maxim, честно говоря, насчёт динамического наполнения Grid View я так деально пока не думал, но то, что Вы сказали, как вариант возможно. Так или иначе, компоновки, будть то Table, Grid или VBox, будут динамически наполняться тем или иным способом, а FXML-файлы уже для приложения будyт содержиать лишь пустые компоновки. Динамическое наполнение - не предмет обсуждения в данном вопросе; здесь же  меня интересует организация раздельного хранения двух версий FXML-файлов: с мок-данными и без них (последний, скорее всего, будет в `src\main\resources\views`).

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то задача аналогично Build Types в Android Studio, но так как такого механизма нет, то альтернатива ему: вынести релиз и debug (mock) отдельными модулями и переключать их в зависимостях, но с реализацией потребуется подумать

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то у вас хранится 2 версии fxml-файла, а в результирующей jar-ке должна оставаться одна, то это задача для maven-resources-plugin через excludes исключить версии с данными, добавляя к их именам файлов какой-то постоянный суффикс, чтобы задать соответствующую маску в настройках плагина.

Comment: @RuslanP, Благодарю Вас за комментарий. Если путь у одноимённых файлов разный, при этом в приложении в явном виде указано, который из них нужен (например, ` loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/views/RootLayout.fxml"));`), то разве неиспользуемые таким образом FXML-файлы будут включены в сборку?

Comment: На сколько мне известно, maven не занимается анализом кода и выявлением используемых ресурсов. Все задается детально конфигурацией ресурсов в pom.xml, если поведение по-умолчанию не устраивает.